# In Rust, how to rename all columns of a Polars Dataframe?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Rust newbie here, I want to use Polars to summarize a dataset that didn't come with column names. If I just use df directly, the error was: cannot borrow `df` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable. How to fix it?

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut df = df! [
        "names" => ["a", "b", "c"],
        "values" => [1, 2, 3],
    ].unwrap();

    let columns = vec![
        "name_chg",
        "value_chg",
    ];

    df
    .get_column_names()
    .iter()
    .zip(columns)
    .for_each(|(old, new)| {df.rename(old, new);}); // cannot borrow `df` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

    println!("{df}");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rename **all** columns, you can use [`df.set_column_names`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.set_column_names).

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut df = df! [
        "names" => ["a", "b", "c"],
        "values" => [1, 2, 3],
    ]
    .unwrap();

    println!("BEFORE: {df}");
    
    let columns = vec!["name_chg", "value_chg"];    
    df.set_column_names(columns.as_slice()).unwrap();

    println!("AFTER: {df}");
}
```

This will produce following output:

```
BEFORE: shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬────────┐
│ names ┆ values │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ i32    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ a     ┆ 1      │
│ b     ┆ 2      │
│ c     ┆ 3      │
└───────┴────────┘
AFTER: shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬───────────┐
│ name_chg ┆ value_chg │
│ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ str      ┆ i32       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╡
│ a        ┆ 1         │
│ b        ┆ 2         │
│ c        ┆ 3         │
└──────────┴───────────┘
```

`set_column_names` API will zip the current columns and the column names you passed in. And then perform the `.rename` operation. It's [equivalent to](https://docs.rs/polars-core/0.38.2/src/polars_core/frame/mod.rs.html#606-630)

```rust
pub fn set_column_names<S: AsRef<str>>(&mut self, names: &[S]) -> PolarsResult<()> {
        // Skipping other part of the code for brevity
        let columns = mem::take(&mut self.columns);
        self.columns = columns
            .into_iter()
            .zip(names)
            .map(|(s, name)| {
                let mut s = s;
                s.rename(name.as_ref());
                s
            })
            .collect();
        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I think I found a solution without cloning the dataframe.

the trick was to end the immutable borrow resulted from `df.get_column_names()`, so I created a new vector of Strings to store the old column names and iterate over the new vector, while making changes to the dataframe. Still not ideal, but sort of acceptable.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut df = df! [
        "names" => ["a", "b", "c"],
        "values" => [1, 2, 3],
    ].unwrap();

    let columns = vec![
        "name_chg",
        "value_chg",
    ];
    // so the way to fix it was to end the immutable borrow created get_column_names()
    let old_cols:Vec<String> = df.get_column_names().iter().map(|s| s.to_owned().to_owned()).collect();

    old_cols
    .iter()
    .zip(columns)
    .for_each(
        |(old, new)| {
            df
            .rename(old, new)
            .expect(format!("cannot rename column {old}").as_str());}); 
    println!("{df}");
}
```